Hide the default select dropdown panel
Can you please let know the css code to hide the default drop down panel highlighted below.

I wrote this code , But it is hiding the options , but not the entire panel
  option { display: none; }
I want to hide that panel because I wanted to create my own custom panel

Hi! Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by panel? I am asking this because by adding the CSS property option {display: none;}, no panel (if what you mean by this is what is inside the square in your image above) is shown.

ALTERNATIVE 1: Disable the Event with JS (shorter)
You will have to create a listener for any click that may occur on the dropdown menu, and the disable it. After doing so, just add your custom code:
document.getElementById("YOUR-SELECT-ID-TAG").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // HERE!!! Write your custom code here
});




ALTERNATIVE 2: Fully Customise the Selection Pannel (longer)
You could try the following code to create a custom select dropdown pannel from scratch:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var dropdownButton = document.getElementById("dropdown-button");
  var dropdownContent = document.querySelector(".dropdown-content");

  dropdownButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // HERE!!! Comment the line below if you want to make the dropdown selection pannel invisible to the user
    dropdownContent.classList.toggle("show");
  });

  document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (!event.target.closest(".custom-dropdown")) {
      dropdownContent.classList.remove("show");
    }
  });
});
.custom-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown-content.show {
  display: block;
}
<div class="custom-dropdown">
  <button id="dropdown-button">Select an option</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Option 1</a>
    <a href="#">Option 2</a>
    <a href="#">Option 3</a>
  </div>
</div>



I suppose that with the code above, there is no need to make the dropdown selection invisible. However, in the snippet there is a comment guiding you to the line in the JS you should comment to make this new dropdown invisible.
Alternatively, you may want to take a look at libraries like Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/), to see if what they offer for customisable dropdowns suits your needs.
Hope this helped! And may the code be with you...

So there is no way to hide the default panel?

You can always prevent the default action with JS by document.getElementById("custom-select").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {     event.preventDefault(); });. Then, you would have to add your custom action after the event.preventDefault(); line. I will update my answer.

Did this solve your initial question?
